# Entities or Models in NestJs code first GraphQl

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I am new to NestJs and GraphQl, I am learning going over some tutorials. It appears to be an inconstancy in the usage of the terminology model or entity.  The nestjs schematics resource generator for graphql code first produces entities, yet the example shown on their website use models.

produces entities:
nx generate @nestjs/schematics:resource generated --language=ts --type=graphql-code-first

uses models no mention of entities in code first approach
https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers

which one terminology is most appropriate?

Thank You,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Both are generally correct. It comes down to naming preferences.

*I* view `entities` as database entities, or database table maps. They map from your database data to a class representation that your code will understand. Models can also be used for this, which I believe is the term that sequilize and mongoose prefer to use.

Models, as described in the docs you linked, are generally your DTOs, your schema objects that you expect the API to accept and respond with.

You'll notice that the generator also generates two `@InputType()` files as well, which will be more closely tied to your incoming DTO while the `entity.ts` will be closer to your response DTO.

So, both are correct, and it comes down to naming preferencec.